# I am getting a pathing error that I do not understand regarding the "diskImageR" package

Tags: r, imagej

I am getting an error when trying to run the diskImageR package, specifically the IJMacro function, regarding an inability to locate ImageJ. This is what I think the error is stating although I do not know for sure.

I already tried changing the path and by following the pdf associated with running the package, but I still get the same error.

```
IJMacro("newProject",imageJLoc ="C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\ImageJ")
```

```
[1] "Searching for application name or filepath:  ImageJ"
Error in ij$runScript(paste(script, IJarguments)) : 
  The imageJ binaries have not been located. Re-initialise the imageJInterface object with the correct location for the imageJ binaries
In addition: Warning message:
In setFilePath(filePath) :
  The ImageJ application could not be found in the common install location on your system
```